# Duplicate UILabel inside UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel, xcode9

Inside `willWillLayoutSubviews()` I call `UIButton's` method `setTileTheme()`, which I created. Result can be seen below - duplicate `UILabel` appears under another one. I have already tried calling my method from `viewDidLoad()` etc., but it didn't help.

Do someone know why I am facing this problem?

```
func setTileTheme(image: UIImage, title: String) {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tintColor = .green
    backgroundColor = .white
    setBorder(width: 1.5, color: .lightGray)
    roundCorners(radius: 5)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let width = self.frame.size.width
    let height = self.frame.size.height
    let offset: CGFloat = width/4.5

    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: 30))
    titleLabel.center = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height-offset)
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.withSize(15)
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.textColor = .darkGray
    self.insertSubview(titleLabel, at: 0)

    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: height/8, left: width/4, bottom: height*3/8, right: width/4)
    setImage(image, for: .disabled)
    setImage(image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: How many times is called `setTileTheme()`? Multiple times. According to the darker color of the label on the bottom, I'd say that there are more at the same position. Called 3 times at least in total. So use a property instead for `titleLabel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIButton already has titleLabel and imageView. What you are doing is you are creating a new label and adding it to buttons view which will not replace the default label.

All that you need is

```
override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectCGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 30)
    }


func setTileTheme(image: UIImage, title: String) {
            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            tintColor = .green
            backgroundColor = .white
            setBorder(width: 1.5, color: .lightGray)
            roundCorners(radius: 5)
            self.layer.masksToBounds = true

            let width = self.frame.size.width
            let height = self.frame.size.height
            let offset: CGFloat = width/4.5

            self.titleLabel?.text = title
            self.titleLabel?.font = titleLabel.font.withSize(15)
            self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            self.titleLabel?.textColor = .darkGray

            imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: height/8, left: width/4, bottom: height*3/8, right: width/4)
            setImage(image, for: .disabled)
            setImage(image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        }
```

I believe you were trying to set the button's title label frame which you can easily set to the default title label of button itself by overriding `titleRect`

**EDIT:**

I can see that you are trying to set the inset to Button's image as well. Adding inset to imageView will simply move the image inside imageView but the imageView frame remains the same. Rather in case you wanna affect the imageView's frame itself then you can simply override

```
override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    //whatever calculation you wanna provide
    //for example
    return CGRect(x: (self.bounds.size.width/2 + 5), y: self.bounds.size.height/2, width: (self.bounds.size.width/2 - 5), height: self.bounds.size.height)
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! After some editing everything works like a charm.

Comment: @crunkz : Am glad I could be of some help :) Happy coding :)